# Yii framework - asset manager

Tags: php, yii

After running into the Yii asset engine I've read the official documentation (http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/148/understanding-assets/). I understand the reasoning behind it but I still find it a bit unelegant that my application has a folder with randomly generated names. Therefore, I have a couple of questions I'm hoping the SO population could give me some feedback on:

1. It's been a while since I delved into new web frameworks (except for ASP.NET MVC, which I quite like). Are asset managers the trend for new web frameworks? This is superficial but I am considering switching to a lighter framework just to avoid this feature alone.
2. I imagine it would be hard to allow the asset manager to be optional but am I the only one that has an issue with it? How about customization of folder names at least?

Perhaps I just have the wrong perspective on things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll start with the second question

> I imagine it would be hard to allow the asset manager to be optional but am I the only one that has an issue with it?

it's very easy to make assets (or at least your own defined assets) optional.. just include them as  and  tags in your layout (with their full non-generated URLs) and you're good to go.

Assets Managers can be very useful for you in many use cases:

1. Resolving dependencies between your script files
2. (with some plugins) Compressing and Minimizing CSS and JS files
3. Caching assets, and more importantly, invalidating the cache (say you want to update the production and want the change in CSS/JS files to be reflected directly to the user's browsers.. what do you do? just delete the contents of the assets folder and the assets will be re-generated automatically... this is conventionally done in other platforms by appending a parameter like (http://example.com/js/very_dynamic_js_file.js?v=32432)

Personal opinion, keep them, you won't notice they're there, and they might be very helpful to you someday.

Some plugins to improve the current behavior of assets: [eClientScript](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/eclientscript/) and [MinScript](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/minscript)

Comment: Invalidating the cache is actually a really good reason. Thanks for the feedback.